# Reading Excel: Column Names truncated to first 64 characters

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel, oledb

I am trying to read an excel spreadsheet through .NET (C#)

Below is a Connection string I use:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Windows\TEMP\96e7a8b720b642388d9dbbca49537678.xls; Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text";`

When I had a look at the schema using:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            result[OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables] = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            result[OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns] = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null);
            result[OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info] = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info, null);
            conn.Close();
        }
```

In `result[OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns]` - all column names are truncated to the first 64 characters.

I need full names of all columns.

Any idea to workaround / solve this issue ?

Much appreciated for viewing this question.

Comment: Seems like 64 characters is a hard limit for Jet.  Can you use excel automation to read the data directly?

Comment: When you say automation - do you mean `Interop` ? Unfortunately - I do not believe it's an option for me as this is an ASP.NET app.

Comment: I've never used any, but I believe there are other libraries available for working with xls files in ASP.net.  Hopefully someone else here will chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim is right, as per this [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/2fb51d81-3d64-445f-806a-519861b561ba) on MSDN. you need to use some third party data access provider as this is the limit for Jet.

**EDIT**:

It can be done without using any third party provider as well. I read this Today on [Microsoft's Support Site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517). According to them its limitation of `Jet 4.0LEDB Source`.